# Remove shadow in Android PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created my `PopupWindow` using a simple `LinearLayout` with a background color.  There is a shadow on the `PopupWindow`.  How do I remove the shadow automatically generated for the `PopupWindow`.  I created a `PopupWindow` with the following:

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);
    pop = new PopupWindow(this);
    pop.setTouchable(false);
    pop.setHeight(200);
    pop.setWidth(200);
    pop.setContentView(view);
    pop.showAtLocation(parentview, 0, 50, 50);
```

Screenshot:

[image: popup shadow]

Comment: Are you able to add a screenshot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it possible that you are missing some code there? I'm not seeing that you are adding the pop to the view.

Anyway, to remove the shadow you have to use this line of code in the PopupWindow:

```
this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

At least that's what worked for me...

Cheers!

Comment: but unable to see the elevation of popupwindow

Answer (score 2):

You can style PopupWindows in your application. This code simply removes native shadows from all your PopupWindows

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupElevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```